Blazor web assembly docker error blazor-devserver.dll does not exist
i'm trying to dockerize blazor web assembly app by docker compose
so, do i need to to run a command to install the SDK because it's referring me to SDK or maybe some dll file doesn't copy to container or i'm not doing the right way for blazor web assembly
here is Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Client/AnswerMe.Client/AnswerMe.Client.csproj", "Client/AnswerMe.Client/"]
COPY ["Client/AnswerMe.Client.Core/AnswerMe.Client.Core.csproj", "Client/AnswerMe.Client.Core/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/Models.Shared/Models.Shared.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/Models.Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Client/AnswerMe.Client/AnswerMe.Client.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Client/AnswerMe.Client"
RUN dotnet build "AnswerMe.Client.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "AnswerMe.Client.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AnswerMe.Client.dll"]

and the docker-compose.yml
  AnswerMe.client:
    container_name: AnswerMe.client
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}answermeclient
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Client/AnswerMe.Client/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080"
      - "8081"

and I'm getting this error in container log file
2024-05-16 09:46:19 The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
2024-05-16 09:46:19   * You intended to execute a .NET application:
2024-05-16 09:46:19       The application '/app/../../../../.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.devserver/8.0.2/tools/blazor-devserver.dll' does not exist.
2024-05-16 09:46:19   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
2024-05-16 09:46:19       No .NET SDKs were found.
2024-05-16 09:46:19 
2024-05-16 09:46:19 Download a .NET SDK:
2024-05-16 09:46:19 https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
2024-05-16 09:46:19 
2024-05-16 09:46:19 Learn about SDK resolution:
2024-05-16 09:46:19 https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found


On what line of dockerfile does it fail? Also - Blazor wasm are just static files and you cannot "run" it, it gets run in a browser. check https://chrissainty.com/containerising-blazor-applications-with-docker-containerising-a-blazor-webassembly-app/
